# Remember value working with will_paginate in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate

Perhaps someone can help me with the following: I am using will_paginate in Rails 5.0 and I read out let's say 24 results per page. The results are taken from Elasticsearch and are ordered per _score. So the first match is going to be the best matching object to whatever the search query was. That all works just fine.

The first object has the highest score, and I am planning to show a progress bar that is filled relative to the score. So the first match will be filled to 100% and the second match will (if the score is lower) be filled less. That all works find too with my current code.

The problem:

On page 1 all works fine. But once I click on page 2 or any other page for that matter the initial highest _score is being lost. And the first match of that particular page is the highest score from this point onwards.

How can I remember the highest score without running the query twice in the controller (once for the particular page, and once to retrieve the highest score)?

Perhaps anyone knows a nifty trick to solve this issue.

**Controller**

```
@users = current_user.search_more_like_this.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 24)
# Problem is that the highest score is recalculated once I change the page.
@highest_score = @users.first._score.to_f
```

**View**

```
  = link_to user_path(user.slug) do
    .progressbar
      %div{:style => "width: #{(user._score/@highest_score)*100}%;"}
        %span{:id => "os" + user.username.to_s, :class => "slickdot"}
        %span{:style => "color: white;padding-left:15px;"}
          = user.username
          = user._score
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. The most trivial one would be tossing the highest score into a cookie (not so safe).
2. The second-most trivial would be tossing the highest score into a signed cookie (safer, only 99.9% bullet-proof)
3. Toss it into a session variable.

There are more, but they're probably far more complex than what your use case would require at this time.

Comment: Session variable it is. :D Thank you, spot on!